# Session Object replication with session.setAttribute

Tags: java, session, hazelcast, setattribute, payara

I have a Cluster as Standalone Instances with Hazelcast and Payara, I added a Session Replication and a Load Balancer with HAProxy. Everything works fine.

When I use a Session Bean all global variables are replicated to the nodes of the cluster but when I try to share an object in a no-SessionBean a few times it doesn't work.
This below is my simple example:

I have a simple page that retrieve 2 list of "String" (Hazelcast Distributed List and Session List):

[Index Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nC4ic.png)

The Bean behind the page has a custom scope.

```
@Named
@RomeoScoped  //this is my custom scope
public class RomeoBean implements Serializable {
```

The "increase" method is called when I click on the "add" button:

```
public void increase(){
    FacesContext currentInstance = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) currentInstance.getExternalContext().getRequest();
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();

    String example  = Math.random() + "";

    if(session != null){
       CopyOnWriteArrayList<String> list = (CopyOnWriteArrayList<String>) session.getAttribute("List");
       list.add(example);
       session.setAttribute("List", list);
    }

    try {
       Context ctx = new InitialContext();
       HazelcastInstance instance = (HazelcastInstance)    ctx.lookup("payara/Hazelcast");
       IList<String> list = instance.getList("list");
       list.add(example);
    } catch (NamingException ex) {
       Logger.getLogger(RomeoBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

After 4 clicks on the button, the situazione is this:

[Click for view Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5Rmc.png)

Only 2 Strings are shared in Session List, while all Strings with Hazelcast.
I need to use my custom scope and in same case the objects must be shared only in the session and not in application (as Hazelcast Distributed List).

Can I fix the problem with "setAttribute" method?

Thanks in advance for the support.

Comment: Can you share your `WebFilter` configuration, probably in your `web.xml` file? In particular, do you have `deferred-write` enabled?

Comment: @emre, this is my web.xml

Comment: Luca, I can't see your web.xml

Comment: @emre, Sorry, that's it . [web.xml](http://37.187.170.237:8080/ww/web.xml)

Comment: There seems to be no `WebFilter` definition in your web.xml. Where do you configure it? I had assumed you were using https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-wm for session replication - is that so?

Comment: I use Payara and Hazelcast configuration is integrated in Payara Server.

Comment: @emre, any ideas?

Comment: Nope, I don't know how Payara uses Hazelcast for session replication. Maybe you can try creating a GitHub issue at https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues - they have a `question` label for this purpose I guess.

Comment: Yes, I have also created an issue on Payara Github. Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make session replication working over Hazelcast in Payara Server, you need to enable Web Container Availability over Hazelcast. See this [screenshot](http://blog.payara.fish/hs-fs/hubfs/Payara_Blog_Images/Creating_a_simple_cluster/4_-_Creating_a_simple_cluster_with_Payara_Server.png?t=1481645284337&width=1238&height=894&name=4_-_Creating_a_simple_cluster_with_Payara_Server.png).

You also need to include the `<distributable/>` element into the `web.xml` in your application, otherwise the session will not be distributed.

Comment: Yes, I enabled Web Container Availability and I have included `<distrubutable/>` tag in the `web.xml`.